# java util scanner throwforunknown source error (cant type input)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a problem with a scanner and I don't really know what's wrong. I have a `Circle` class and I want to make check loop for its radius on the constructor. Here is the code:

```
Circle(double x, double y, String color, double radius) {
    super(x, y, color); // constructor from class shape which is extended by circle
    Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (radius <= 0)
    {
        System.out.println("radius has to be > 0.....Give radius again");
        if (r.hasNextDouble())
        {
            radius = r.nextDouble();
        }
        else
        {
            r.nextLine(); //25th line
        } 
    }
    this.radius = radius;
    r.close();
}
```

If I put as a radius 0 I don't get the chance to make an input and it gives me this message:

```
radius has to be > 0.....Give radius again
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException:No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
at pack.Circle.<init>(Circle.java:25)
at pack.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Well obviously you guessed right.Problem solved after deleting all .close(); but does that means that i should never close a scanner? and what does then close() does?/////Thank you very much!!

Comment: That is good to hear. I added an answer which may also answer the other questions you have.

Answer (score 1):

[`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) throws the `NoSuchElementException` if it couldn't read a line from the provided [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html). Since you're using `System.in` as your input stream and since it will block the thread until it could read the requested line, there is only one reason left, which can cause such a problem: *the stream is already closed*.

You're calling [`Scanner.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29) in your `Circle` constructor, which will not only close the scanner, it will also close the used input stream. That means,  the input stream, referenced by the variable `System.in` is closed, and can't be opened again. So if you already created a circle, or closed the stream somewhere else in your code you will get the mentioned exception.

To fix the problem, just remove every `close` call for every reader, like [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) or [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), which uses `System.in` as its source stream.

And then you should think about extracting the `r` variable into a dedicated class. Then you can create the `Scanner` *once* and use it everywhere where you want to request user input. You can close that scanner if you like to close the application and perform a cleanup.